# Count number of Mondays in a given date range

Tags: c#, datetime, date, datediff

Given a date range, I need to know how many Mondays (or Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc) are in that range.

I am currently working in C#.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this:

```
static int CountDays(DayOfWeek day, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    TimeSpan ts = end - start;                       // Total duration
    int count = (int)Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays / 7);   // Number of whole weeks
    int remainder = (int)(ts.TotalDays % 7);         // Number of remaining days
    int sinceLastDay = (int)(end.DayOfWeek - day);   // Number of days since last [day]
    if (sinceLastDay < 0) sinceLastDay += 7;         // Adjust for negative days since last [day]

    // If the days in excess of an even week are greater than or equal to the number days since the last [day], then count this one, too.
    if (remainder >= sinceLastDay) count++;          

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon B...this is the answer I was looking for.  I was close, my missing link was what to do with the remainder.

Comment: Is there any other way that you can simplify this code?

Answer (score 22):

Since you're using C#, if you're using C#3.0, you can use LINQ.

Assuming you have an Array/List/IQueryable etc that contains your dates as DateTime types:

```
DateTime[] dates = { new DateTime(2008,10,6), new DateTime(2008,10,7)}; //etc....

var mondays = dates.Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday); // = {10/6/2008}
```

Added:

Not sure if you meant grouping them and counting them, but here's how to do that in LINQ as well:

```
var datesgrouped = from d in dates
                   group d by d.DayOfWeek into grouped
                   select new { WeekDay = grouped.Key, Days = grouped };

foreach (var g in datesgrouped)
{
    Console.Write (String.Format("{0} : {1}", g.WeekDay,g.Days.Count());
}
```

Comment: Don't know; but I voted it up one to compensate.  I like your LINQ samples.

Comment: Agreed, the samples are great.

Comment: It's being voted down I think for 2 reasons
1: The question was about a date range, not a list of dates; so your example doesn't work.
2: Looping through the date range would take a long time if you had to do it for a large range and a large number of times.

Answer (score 21):

It's fun to look at different algorithms for calculating day of week, and @Gabe Hollombe's pointing to WP on the subject was a great idea (and I remember implementing [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) in COBOL about twenty years ago), but it was rather along the line of handing someone a blueprint of a clock when all they asked what time it was.

In C#:

```
    private int CountMondays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int mondayCount = 0;

        for (DateTime dt = startDate; dt < endDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1.0))
        {
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                mondayCount++;
            }
        }

        return mondayCount;
    }
```

This of course does not evaluate the end date for "Mondayness", so if this was desired, make the for loop evaluate

```
dt < endDate.AddDays(1.0)
```

Comment: I really like how you use a DateTime for the iterator.

Comment: I used this to get a list of Monday(Tuesday, Wednesday, etc) dates in a range of datetime, thanks

Comment: The accepted answer beats this in terms of performance, but this answer is more readable and understandable in my opinion.  Thanks @Cyberherbalist.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some pseudocode:

```
DifferenceInDays(Start, End) / 7   // Integer division discarding remainder
+ 1 if DayOfWeek(Start) <= DayImLookingFor
+ 1 if DayOfWeek(End)   >= DayImLookingFor
- 1
```

Where `DifferenceInDays` returns `End - Start` in days, and `DayOfWeek` returns the day of the week as an integer.  It doesn't really matter what mapping `DayOfWeek` uses, as long as it is increasing and matches up with `DayImLookingFor`.

Note that this algorithm assumes the date range is inclusive.  If `End` should not be part of the range, you'll have to adjust the algorithm slightly.

Translating to C# is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Any particular language and therefore date format?

If dates are represented as a count of days, then the difference between two values plus one (day), and divide by 7, is most of the answer.  If both end dates are the day in question, add one.

*Edited:* corrected 'modulo 7' to 'divide by 7' - thanks.  And that is integer division.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the algorithm you are proposing, the maximum result for any date range would be 6 since that is the max result for Modulo 7 of any number. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, it should be divided by 7, not mod 7

Comment: Mea culpa - I meant (integer) division!

Comment: @Simucal: When originally asked, there were just 3 tags - not C# too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, if you want to get specific week days between two dates

```
public List<DateTime> GetSelectedDaysInPeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<DayOfWeek> daysToCheck)
{
    var selectedDates = new List<DateTime>();

    if (startDate >= endDate)
        return selectedDates; //No days to return

    if (daysToCheck == null || daysToCheck.Count == 0)
        return selectedDates; //No days to select

    try
    {
        //Get the total number of days between the two dates
        var totalDays = (int)endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays;

        //So.. we're creating a list of all dates between the two dates:
        var allDatesQry = from d in Enumerable.Range(1, totalDays)
                             select new DateTime(
                                                  startDate.AddDays(d).Year,
                                                  startDate.AddDays(d).Month,
                                                  startDate.AddDays(d).Day);

        //And extracting those weekdays we explicitly wanted to return
        var selectedDatesQry = from d in allDatesQry
                                  where daysToCheck.Contains(d.DayOfWeek)
                                  select d;

        //Copying the IEnumerable to a List
        selectedDates = selectedDatesQry.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error
        //...

        //And re-throw
        throw;
    }
    return selectedDates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the smallest possible number to make the first day a Monday.  Subtract the smallest possible number to make the last day a Monday.  Calculate the difference in days and divide by 7.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dates to Julian Day Number, then do a little bit of math. Since Mondays are  zero mod 7, you could do the calculation like this:

```
JD1=JulianDayOf(the_first_date)
JD2=JulianDayOf(the_second_date)
Round JD1 up to nearest multiple of 7
Round JD2 up to nearest multiple of 7
d = JD2-JD1
nMondays = (JD2-JD1+7)/7    # integer divide
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same need today. I started with the *cjm* function since I don't understand the *JonB* function and since the *Cyberherbalist* function is not linear.

I had have to correct

```
DifferenceInDays(Start, End) / 7   // Integer division discarding remainder
+ 1 if DayOfWeek(Start) <= DayImLookingFor
+ 1 if DayOfWeek(End)   >= DayImLookingFor
- 1
```

to

```
DifferenceInDays(Start, End) / 7   // Integer division discarding remainder
+ 1 if DayImLookingFor is between Start.Day and End.Day
```

With the between function that return true if, starting from the start day, we meet first the dayImLookingFor before the endDay.

I have done the between function by computing the number of day from startDay to the other two days:

```
private int CountDays(DateTime start, DateTime end, DayOfWeek selectedDay)
{
    if (start.Date > end.Date)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int totalDays = (int)end.Date.Subtract(start.Date).TotalDays;
    DayOfWeek startDay = start.DayOfWeek;
    DayOfWeek endDay = end.DayOfWeek;
    ///look if endDay appears before or after the selectedDay when we start from startDay.
    int startToEnd = (int)endDay - (int)startDay;
    if (startToEnd < 0)
    {
        startToEnd += 7;
    }
    int startToSelected = (int)selectedDay - (int)startDay;
    if (startToSelected < 0)
    {
        startToSelected += 7;
    }
    bool isSelectedBetweenStartAndEnd = startToEnd >= startToSelected;
    if (isSelectedBetweenStartAndEnd)
    {
        return totalDays / 7 + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return totalDays / 7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a collection of integers showing how many times each day of the week occurs within a date range

```
    int[] CountDays(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
    {
        var totalDays = lastDate.Date.Subtract(firstDate.Date).TotalDays + 1;
        var weeks = (int)Math.Floor(totalDays / 7);

        var result = Enumerable.Repeat<int>(weeks, 7).ToArray();
        if (totalDays % 7 != 0)
        {
            int firstDayOfWeek = (int)firstDate.DayOfWeek;
            int lastDayOfWeek = (int)lastDate.DayOfWeek;
            if (lastDayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek)
                lastDayOfWeek += 7;
            for (int dayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek++)
                result[dayOfWeek % 7]++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Or a slight variation which lets you do FirstDate.TotalDaysOfWeeks(SecondDate) and returns a Dictionary

```
    public static Dictionary<DayOfWeek, int> TotalDaysOfWeeks(this DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
    {
        var totalDays = lastDate.Date.Subtract(firstDate.Date).TotalDays + 1;
        var weeks = (int)Math.Floor(totalDays / 7);

        var resultArray = Enumerable.Repeat<int>(weeks, 7).ToArray();
        if (totalDays % 7 != 0)
        {
            int firstDayOfWeek = (int)firstDate.DayOfWeek;
            int lastDayOfWeek = (int)lastDate.DayOfWeek;
            if (lastDayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek)
                lastDayOfWeek += 7;
            for (int dayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek++)
                resultArray[dayOfWeek % 7]++;
        }
        var result = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, int>();
        for (int dayOfWeek = 0; dayOfWeek < 7; dayOfWeek++)
            result[(DayOfWeek)dayOfWeek] = resultArray[dayOfWeek];
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit Modified Code is here works and Tested by me

```
        private int CountDays(DayOfWeek day, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            int dayCount = 0;

            for (DateTime dt = startDate; dt < endDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1.0))
            {
                if (dt.DayOfWeek == day)
                {
                    dayCount++;
                }
            }

            return dayCount;
        }
```

Example:

```
int Days = CountDays(DayOfWeek.Friday, Convert.ToDateTime("2019-07-04"), 
             Convert.ToDateTime("2019-07-27")).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed it in VB.NET and converted it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a report.  I needed the number of workdays between two dates.
I could have cycled through the dates and counted but my discrete math training wouldn't let me.  Here is a function I wrote in VBA to get the number of workdays between two dates.  I'm sure .net has a similar WeekDay function.

```
   1  
   2  ' WorkDays
   3  ' returns the number of working days between two dates
   4  Public Function WorkDays(ByVal dtBegin As Date, ByVal dtEnd As Date) As Long
   5  
   6     Dim dtFirstSunday As Date
   7     Dim dtLastSaturday As Date
   8     Dim lngWorkDays As Long
   9  
  10     ' get first sunday in range
  11     dtFirstSunday = dtBegin + ((8 - Weekday(dtBegin)) Mod 7)
  12  
  13     ' get last saturday in range
  14     dtLastSaturday = dtEnd - (Weekday(dtEnd) Mod 7)
  15  
  16     ' get work days between first sunday and last saturday
  17     lngWorkDays = (((dtLastSaturday - dtFirstSunday) + 1) / 7) * 5
  18  
  19     ' if first sunday is not begin date
  20     If dtFirstSunday <> dtBegin Then
  21  
  22        ' assume first sunday is after begin date
  23        ' add workdays from begin date to first sunday
  24        lngWorkDays = lngWorkDays + (7 - Weekday(dtBegin))
  25  
  26     End If
  27  
  28     ' if last saturday is not end date
  29     If dtLastSaturday <> dtEnd Then
  30  
  31        ' assume last saturday is before end date
  32        ' add workdays from last saturday to end date
  33        lngWorkDays = lngWorkDays + (Weekday(dtEnd) - 1)
  34  
  35     End If
  36  
  37     ' return working days
  38     WorkDays = lngWorkDays
  39  
  40  End Function
```

Comment: WeekDay is property on the DateTime type in .NET, so aren't WorkDays just dates where the Weekday is in 2,3,4,5 (assuming 1=Sunday)?

Answer (score 0):

```
private System.Int32 CountDaysOfWeek(System.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, System.DateTime date1, System.DateTime date2)
{
  System.DateTime EndDate;
  System.DateTime StartDate;

  if (date1 > date2)
  {
    StartDate = date2;
    EndDate = date1;
  }
  else
  {
    StartDate = date1;
    EndDate = date2;
  }

  while (StartDate.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(1);

  return EndDate.Subtract(StartDate).Days / 7 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, I thought I'd run a test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldFindFridaysInTimeSpan()
{
    //reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range

    var spanOfSixtyDays = new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0);
    var setOfDates = new List<DateTime>(spanOfSixtyDays.Days);
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    for(int i = 0; i < spanOfSixtyDays.Days; i++)
    {
        setOfDates.Add(now.AddDays(i));
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(setOfDates.Count == 60,
        "The expected number of days is not here.");

    var fridays = setOfDates.Where(i => i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);

    Assert.IsTrue(fridays.Count() > 0,
        "The expected Friday days are not here.");
    Assert.IsTrue(fridays.First() == setOfDates.First(i => i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday),
        "The expected first Friday day is not here.");
    Assert.IsTrue(fridays.Last() == setOfDates.Last(i => i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday),
        "The expected last Friday day is not here.");
}
```

My use of `TimeSpan` is a bit of overkill---actually I wanted to query `TimeSpan` directly.