# calculating number of days between 2 dates chosen from calendar(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, html

im using vs 2010.

the below code is how i've put 2 dates in the 2 text boxes.I want to know how i can calculate the no. of days between them.If possible can u tell me how to also take off Sundays from that number.thnx in advance

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.Visible = true;

}
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
    Calendar1.Visible = false;
}
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar2.Visible = true;

}
protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox4.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
    Calendar2.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
var days = (Calendar1.SelectedDate - Calendar2.SelectedDate).TotalDays;
```

However, this does not exclude Sundays.

Comment: It should be noted that subtraction of two DateTime objects would return an instance of TimeSpan http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx which is useful in many situations.

Comment: In addition, to calculate the sundays between a range. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Substract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) to do the calculation.

Calculating the sundays and removing them should be easy, using the returned TimeSpan object.

**EDIT**

Jon is correct with his comment, and its not trivial to get the sundays using just the TimeSpan. The link provided in the comment bellow (by louis) seems to do this part of the job though

Comment: How many Sundays lie within a `TimeSpan` of 9 days? You can't *just* use the `TimeSpan`...

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a `TimeSpan` by Subtracting two `DateTime` values.

The following code should get you started.

```
 if ( Calendar2.SelectedDate != null && Calendar1.SelectDate != null )
 {
      TimeSpan Value;
      if ( Calendar2.SelectedDate >= Calendar1.SelectedDate )
           Value = (Calendar2.SelectedDate - Calendar1.SelectedDate).TotalDays;
      else
          Value = (Calendar1.SelectedDate - Calendar2.SelectedDate).TotalDays; 
 }
```

I currently do not have access to Visual Studio, I believe this to compile, its just a quick and dirty suggestion.

> public Nullable SelectedDate { get; set; }