# How many Mondays in a Month Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, date

I'm trying to determine how many mondays there is between two dates. 
These dates will be inserted by a datetimepicker

I know there are similar threads to this but they're all in PHP or VBScript.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your title says "Mondays in a Month" but your question text asks about "how many mondays there are between two dates". Which one do you want?

Comment: those two dates are the beggining of the month and the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post tells you how to do it in C#.  [Count number of Mondays in a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range)

I have run the code through a converter below.  Have not tested it.

```
Private Shared Function CountDays(day As DayOfWeek, start As DateTime, [end] As DateTime) As Integer

   Dim ts As TimeSpan = [end] - start

   ' Total duration
   Dim count As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays / 7))

   ' Number of whole weeks
   Dim remainder As Integer = CInt(ts.TotalDays Mod 7)

   ' Number of remaining days
   Dim sinceLastDay As Integer = CInt([end].DayOfWeek - day)

   ' Number of days since last [day]
   If sinceLastDay < 0 Then
      sinceLastDay += 7
   End If

   ' Adjust for negative days since last [day]
   ' If the days in excess of an even week are greater than or equal to the number days since the last [day], then count this one, too.

   If remainder >= sinceLastDay Then
     count += 1
   End If

   Return count

End Function
```