# How many Fridays are there in the month ?. Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net

**I want help writing a code to calculate the number of Fridays in a particular month, for example January or February .... etc.**

Comment: [Count number of Mondays in a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248273/7444103) -- Translated: [How many Mondays in a Month Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388280/7444103)

Answer (score 1):

You could use such an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement) method:

```
Public Iterator Function GetWeekDaysInMonth(year As Int32, month As Int32, dayOfWeek As DayOfWeek) As IEnumerable(Of Date)
    Dim day = New Date(year, month, 1)
    Dim diff As Int32 = (7 + (day.DayOfWeek - dayOfWeek)) Mod 7
    day = day.AddDays(-1 * diff)
    If day.Month <> month Then day = day.AddDays(7)
    While day.Month = month
        Yield day
        day = day.AddDays(7)
    End While
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim countFridaysYanuary = GetWeekDaysInMonth(2022, 1, DayOfWeek.Friday).Count()
Dim countFridaysFebruary = GetWeekDaysInMonth(2022, 2, DayOfWeek.Friday).Count()
```

If you want them all in a list, use:

```
Dim fridaysInYanuary = GetWeekDaysInMonth(2022, 1, DayOfWeek.Friday).ToList()
```

If you just want the first:

```
Dim firstFridayInJanuary = GetWeekDaysInMonth(2022, 1, DayOfWeek.Friday).First()
```

If you want to output all fridays of the year 2022 per month, you can use:

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To 12
    Dim fridays = GetWeekDaysInMonth(2022, i, DayOfWeek.Friday)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", fridays.Select(Function(d) d.ToShortDateString())))
Next
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ptUlX

Comment: Thank you my dear friend  ( Tim Schmelter )