# Get dates on certain weekday between two dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I receive a start and end `DateTime`.

From this, I want to create a `List<DateTime>` of all the dates that are between these two dates, but only on specified weekdays, such as the Monday.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range - second answer down.
Additionally, if you need help in creating the range of dates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: [Using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31247959/205233) (direct link to answer mentioned by @TVOHM)

Comment: Hah, didn't see that one - that's actually quite a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a list of dates as explained in [Create an array or List of all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates):

```
public List<DateTime> GetDatesBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
                          .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                          .ToList();
    return dates;
}
```

Now to filter this list to only include weekdays you're interested in is equally trivial by selecting only dates `Where()` the [DayOfWeek property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) is one of the requested weekdays:

```
public List<DateTime> GetDatesBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end, params DayOfWeek[] weekdays)
{
    bool allDays = weekdays == null || !weekdays.Any();

    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
                          .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                          .Where(d => allDays || weekdays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
                          .ToList();
    return dates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow function return a `List<DateTime>` contains all dates from `startDate` to `endDate` have given `dayOfWeek`:

```
public static List<DateTime> Get_DayofWeek_DatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

    // Total dates in given range. "+ 1" include endDate
    double totalDates = (endDate.Date - startDate.Date).TotalDays + 1;

    // Find first "dayOfWeek" date from startDate
    int i = dayOfWeek - startDate.DayOfWeek;
    if (i < 0) i += 7;

    // Add all "dayOfWeek" dates in given range
    for (int j = i; j < totalDates; j += 7) list.Add(startDate.AddDays(j));

    return list;
}
```