# Finding date for given year,month and day name in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I find dates in c# if year , month AND day is given.

e.g. Given month = 03, year = 2016. I need to find dates in which saturday occurs.

The expected output [we can see that saturday in 2016/03 occurs in following dates]:
    05/03/2016
    12/03/2016
    19/03/2016
    26/03/2016

Comment: You should maybe start to work on it first.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range) should help.

Comment: @AliK : Thanks it helped.

Comment: @YassinHajaj : I have worked on it wth Alik suggestion and I found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<DateTime> saturdays = new List<DateTime>();
        for(int i=0;i<DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month), i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, i);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                saturdays.Add(dt);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int year = 2016, month = 3;
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
var dates = 
    // generate dates for all days in the month
    Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
    .Select(x => new DateTime(year, month, x))
    // select only those of particular dayOfWeek
    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With Linq, making no assumption about the number of days in the month:

```
    static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetSaturdaysInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
            .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
            .Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DateTime` based on year and month variables as a first day of that month, iterate through the first day of the next month and check it's [`DayOfWeek` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek) is `Saturday` or not. Like;

```
var month = 3;
var year = 2016;

var start = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
var end = start.AddMonths(1);

while (start < end)
{
    if (start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    start = start.AddDays(1);
}
```

Prints

```
05/03/2016
12/03/2016
19/03/2016
26/03/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one (very simple) possibility:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);
var list = new List<DateTime>();
for(int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(2016, 3); i++) {
    var date = startDate.AddDays(i);
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) list.Add(date);
}
```

You create the startDate with the first day of the month.
Then you iterate over all days of the month and add the Saturdays to a list.