# Number of fridays between two dates (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I need to calculate the number of Fridays, Through 2 dates
i have : DateTimePicker1 , DateTimePicker2 , button1 , TextBox1

Presumably :
if  DateTimePicker1 = 1-1-2019 "Monday"
and DateTimePicker2 = 6-1-2017 "Sunday"
* When pressing the button1 , TextBox1 =1

i try this :

```
dim count as integer
dim I as integer

for i = DateTimePicker1.value.DayOfWeek To DateTimePicker.value.DayOfWeek
  if i = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
    count = count + 1
  end if
Next
TextBox1 = Count
```

Comment: SO is not a place where you post questions of the form "I want to do this, tell me how".  It's a place for questions of the form "I'm trying to do this, here's how I'm trying to do it, this is what happens when I try, how do I fix it". If you have no idea what to do then it's too soon to post here. It means that you have given the problem any real thought.

Comment: If you had to do this task manually, could you do it? I'll wager that you could, which means that you are able to work out steps to perform to get it done. Pick up a pen and paper and write down those steps. Put some thought into what you need to do and write it down in detail. Formalise it as a numbered list. When you're done, you have an algorithm. Now you know exactly what your code needs to do so you can write code to do it. Don't even think of writing code until you know what it has to do. I'm not talking about the result but the steps to get to the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think your response is better than the solution itself
Thanks again

Comment: This was my first post on the site, I've actually tried to solve the problem,
I also give it a lot of attention, the missing link is that I did not share what I have just tried
The code is currently available. Thank you for your kind reply

Comment: This problem has been solved several times before. Here is [one C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range). Converting to vb.net should be straight-forward.

Comment: Those `DayOfWeek` values are only going to be numbers in the range 0 to 6, so that's obviously not a loop you want to use. Think `Do` or `While` loop and think using `AddDays` to increase a `Date` from a start value to an end value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have really tried your own code, because i see there are errors in syntax and even the approach is not correct also. Anyway you can try the following approach :

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim TotalDays As Long = DateDiff("d", DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value) + 1
For i As Long = 1 To TotalDays
    If startDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
        count += 1
    End If
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
Next
TextBox1.Text = count.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to compare .ToShortDateString for the Do loop. It gets rid of the interference form the Time component.

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
            Dim count As Integer
            Dim d As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
            Dim strEndDate = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString
            'This will count the start date if it is Friday but not the end date
            'If you need to add the end dat then use the .AddDays(1) on the DateTimePicker2
            Do Until d.ToShortDateString = strEndDate
                If d.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
                    count += 1
                End If
                d = d.AddDays(1)
            Loop
            TextBox1.Text = count.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `Date` property and avoid the use of strings?