# How to calculate WeekEnds in minutes inbetween the two given dates by considering the time also

Tags: c#

I have two fields startdate and enddate where I need to calculate how many weekends in between those two dates and show them in minutes. For example start date is 01/11/2019 00:00:00 and end date as 03/11/2019 12:00:00, I should get the output in total Saturday and partial Sunday as 1.5 days weekend in between the given dates

I tried the following code which is not calculating the time on weekends with given scenario

```
public int CountOfWeekEnds(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int weekEndCount = 0;
        if (startDate > endDate)
        {
            DateTime temp = startDate;
            startDate = endDate;
            endDate = temp;
        }
        TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
        int days = diff.Days;
        for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
        {
            var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
            if (testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                if (testDate.Minute > 0)
                {
                    weekEndCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return weekEndCount;
    }
```

Showing output as 2 days of weekend instead of 1.5 days in between the dates. Please suggest how I achieve this

Comment: `.AddDays` does not change the `TimeOfDay`, so `testDate.Minute` will always be the same as `startDate.Minute`.

Comment: Also, your method returns an `int`, so it will never return a decimal value like `1.5`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, by `weekends` you mean both `saturday`and `sunday`.

I use this code to compute how many `DayOfWeek` exists between two dates.

```
public static int CountOfWeekEnds(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    return CountDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday, start, end) + CountDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday, start, end);
}

public static int CountDays(DayOfWeek day, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    TimeSpan ts = end - start;                       // Total duration
    int count = (int)Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays / 7);   // Number of whole weeks
    int remainder = (int)(ts.TotalDays % 7);         // Number of remaining days
    int sinceLastDay = end.DayOfWeek - day;          // Number of days since last [day]
    if (sinceLastDay < 0) sinceLastDay += 7;         // Adjust for negative days since last [day]

    // If the days in excess of an even week are greater than or equal to the number days since the last [day], then count this one, too.
    if (remainder >= sinceLastDay) count++;          

    return count;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248525/5734097)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should change to make this work:

1. Since we want to return the number of weekend days as a decimal, we need to change our return type to something that represents that, like a `double`.
2. Then, when we calculate our days, we need to get the fraction of the day by dividing the hours by 24. In my example below, I went even further and calculated the fraction of days based on the number of `Ticks` instead of the `Hours`.
3. And finally, when we add days, we should use only the `Date` part of the result so that the time is set to midnight, except for the very last day, where we want to use the specified time.

For example:

```
public static double GetWeekendDaysCount(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (start == end) return 0;

    if (start > end)
    {
        DateTime temp = start;
        start = end;
        end = temp;
    }

    double weekendDays = 0;
    var current = start;

    // To be super accurate, we can calculate based on Ticks instead of hours
    var ticksInADay = (double)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Ticks;

    while (current <= end)
    {
        if (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || 
            current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            // If the time is midnight, count it as one day,
            // otherwise add a fraction of a day
            weekendDays += current.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.Zero
                ? current.TimeOfDay.Ticks / ticksInADay
                : 1;
        }

        // Add a day and set the time to midnight by using 'Date'
        current = current.AddDays(1).Date;

            // Unless we're on the last day, then we want 
            // to use the TimeOfDay that was specified
        if (current == end.Date) current = end;
    }

    return weekendDays;
}
```