# Count days of the week by month between two dates

Tags: c#

I ran into a problem on the project, in fact, what is the essence:

There is a range given by two dates. In this range, you need to find the names of the months included in this range, which has already been done, but you still need to find the number of days of the week (for example, Mondays) monthly included in this range.

For example:

Start date - 01.01.2023

End date - 02/28/202

Months in the range - January, February

Mondays in January - 5

Mondays in February - 4

Tell me, do you have any ideas how to do something similar or maybe someone has similar ready-made solutions?

Thank you in advance!

I suggest that it is necessary to count everything in a loop and with arrays, however I am not very good at them yet, so I need help

Comment: ...is this for a homework assignment or something?

Comment: _"I suggest that it is necessary to count everything in a loop and with arrays"_ - I'm going to disagree with your suggestion there... we have better techniques now than we did in the 1970s [when "loops" and "arrays" were vogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_structured_programming) - to suggest building a solution from "loops and arrays" is like suggesting building a sturdy western-European style house out of bricks and cement: you're not _wrong_, but it's not a particular helpful suggestion either.

Comment: https://planetcalc.com/7741/ - This is how you can get weeks and days between 2 dates.

Comment: A week will have all week days. When considering the remainder you can calculate the additional week days considering the day of week of the initial date.

Comment: Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range

Comment: @dai. I agree with you on arrays, but loops are still fundamental. About one a week I see a _modern_ LINQ-based solution to a simple problem here that's O(N^2) or O(N x log(N)), when a simple O(N) solution using a loop would work

Comment: @Flydog57 That's not inherent in Linq - what you're describing is just people misunderstanding how to apply Linq correctly.

Comment: I don't disagree. But, it's a lot easier to visualize what's going on in a simple loop

Comment: @Flydog57 \*throws a Haskell book at you\*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of Mondays in a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248273/count-number-of-mondays-in-a-given-date-range)

Comment: @sbrwdmitriy: does my answer help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like homework.  I don't do homework for other people (I had enough of that way back when I was a student).  I do help out.

I ignored @Dai and his flying Haskell book, and used a loop to show how this can be done.

First, consider the simple `for` loop.  A `for` statement has three parts:

```
for(initialize; validate; updateAtEndOfLoop)
```

Typically, this iterates over an integer.  For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someMaxValue; ++i) {
    DoSomethingWith(i);
}
```

That code is equivalent to:

```
{
    var i = 0;                     //initialize
    while (i < someMaxValue) {     //validate
        DoSomethingWith(i);
        ++i;                       //updateAtEndOfLoop
    }
}
```

But, there's nothing that says that `for` loops have to work with integers, in particular, they can work with `DateTime`s.

Consider this code:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 22);
var endDate = DateTime.Today;
var increment = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

That sets up a start date last month, and end date today, and an increment value that is a `TimeSpan`.  In particular, you can add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime`, and that addition will result in a new `DateTime`.

So, I can say:

```
for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date += increment) {
    DoSomethingWith(date);
}
```

One other thing of note is that `DateTime`s have a `DayOfWeek` property.  `DayOfWeek` is an `enum` that corresponds to the days of the week.  If you convert an enum to a string (with `.ToString`, it will render as the string-valued day of the week (like `"Sunday"`).

In my test case, I used this as the body of my loop:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"{date.Year}-{date.Month}-{date.Day}: {date.DayOfWeek} ({(int)date.DayOfWeek})");
```

That resulted in this showing up in my `Output` pane in Visual Studio:

```
2023-1-22: Sunday (0)
2023-1-23: Monday (1)
2023-1-24: Tuesday (2)
2023-1-25: Wednesday (3)
2023-1-26: Thursday (4)
2023-1-27: Friday (5)
2023-1-28: Saturday (6)
2023-1-29: Sunday (0)
2023-1-30: Monday (1)
2023-1-31: Tuesday (2)
2023-2-1: Wednesday (3)
2023-2-2: Thursday (4)
2023-2-3: Friday (5)
2023-2-4: Saturday (6)
2023-2-5: Sunday (0)
2023-2-6: Monday (1)
2023-2-7: Tuesday (2)
2023-2-8: Wednesday (3)
2023-2-9: Thursday (4)
2023-2-10: Friday (5)
2023-2-11: Saturday (6)
2023-2-12: Sunday (0)
2023-2-13: Monday (1)
2023-2-14: Tuesday (2)
2023-2-15: Wednesday (3)
2023-2-16: Thursday (4)
2023-2-17: Friday (5)
2023-2-18: Saturday (6)
2023-2-19: Sunday (0)
2023-2-20: Monday (1)
2023-2-21: Tuesday (2)
```

This should give you enough to solve your problem.